# Why is my express server not sending cookies to my frontend which uses next.js/react?

Tags: node.js, heroku, cookies, https, express-session

So I decided to create a Next.js project and an Express server for passport authentication (maybe it was not a good choice?). On local development, I would enter my login information, and a session would be created on my database, and passport would automatically send a cookie which would be set on my client side, allowing the app to proceed to the dashboard page. However, after uploading backend to Heroku and frontend on vercel, configuring ACM SSL on both, and using the following cors and express-session settings, the cookie simply won't be set on the client side ( I see no set-cookie header in network tab and the app redirects me back to login since no cookie was there).

My cors and express-session configuration:

```
app.use(
  expressSession({
    secret: process.env.SECRET_COOKIE_SESSION_KEY,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      httpOnly: false,
      secure: true,
      sameSite: "none",
      path: "/", // Set the path to '/'
      maxAge: parseInt(process.env.MAX_COOKIE_AGE_MILLIS),
    },
    store: sessionStore, // Use the express-mysql-session store for session storage
  })
);

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: process.env.BASE_CLIENT_URL,
    methods: ["GET", "POST"],
    allowedHeaders: ["Content-Type", "Authorization"],
    exposedHeaders: ["X-Custom-Header", "Set-Cookie"],
    credentials: true,
    preflightContinue: true,
  })
);
```

Note: httpOnly: true  wasn't working either. Also, omitting the domain flag did not change anything, but putting it there causes a warning in the network tab stating the domain is invalid with respect to host url.

Here are my frontend and backend apps for reference:

https://blood-frontend.vercel.app/login

https://bloodsense-backend-app-50ad20c4b656.herokuapp.com/

Apologies in advance if anything is unclear. Please let me know if any more info is needed!

**Edit:**

To ensure clarity, here's the flow of the login feature of my app:

1. Next.js client sends request to the login route of my server. The Server responds back with status200, and the login client redirects itself to the dashboard page. Here's the login route:

   ```
    router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
    const middlewareFunc = passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
      if (err){
        console.log(err)
      }
      if (!user) 
        res.status(401).send(`Username or password is incorrect`);

      console.log(req.user) //prints user object as expected. expressSession creates a session on the mySQL DB too

      if (user) {
        req.login(user, (err) => {
          if (err) throw err;

          console.log(res.getHeader("Set-Cookie")); //prints undefined on production
          console.log(res.getHeader("set-cookie")); //undefined
          console.log(res.getHeaders()["set-cookie"]); //undefined

          //this response is sent
          res.status(200).send({
            success: true,
            message: "User Logged In Successfully",
          });
        });
      }
    });
    middlewareFunc(req, res, next);
   ```

   });
2. My dashboard page checks the auth status beforehand through SSR

```html
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  // Perform authentication and authorization checks here

  const user = await checkAuthenticationWithCookie(
    context.req.headers.cookie
  );
  console.log("cookie->", context.req.headers.cookie); //undefined
  //user is also undefined
  if (!user) {
    console.log("The user was not authenticated properly"); //prints
    console.log(context.req.headers.cookie); //this prints undefined
    return {
      redirect: {
        destination: "/login",
        permanent: false,
      },
    };
  }


  return {
    props: {
      user: user,
    },
  };
}
```

3. I get redirected to login page as seen in the dashboard getServerSideProps page.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to look into.
 You are setting httpOnly to false. You might want to reconsider that. 
Try adding this to your express's index.js file before middlewares in production

```js
app.set('trust proxy', 1)
// or
app.enable('trust proxy')
```

Comment: Yes, I have put these options before my middleware. I get the same behavior regardless, even after setting httpOnly to true. I get a preflight login request, followed by another login request right after it. It is interesting how I can now see the Set-Cookie header in the second "actual" login response header, but when I print out the cookies from the res.getHeader stuff on the server, it prints undefined. I made some updates to the question to allow for more clarification.